# How to create multiple plots in python in loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have following table where we have columns topic, score1, score2, score3, score4.

```
| id | score1 | score2  | score3   | score4  |
|----|--------|---------|----------|---------|
| 1  | 0.05   | 0.0608  | 0.476464 | 0.53535 |
| 1  | 0.08   | 0.0333  | 0.8263   | 0.9463  |
| 1  | 0.05   | 0.0926  | 0.8694   | 0.9903  |
| 2  | 0.08   | 0.0425  | 0.1948   | 0.3958  |
| 2  | 0.09   | 0.0992  | 0.1238   | 0.1937  |
| 4  | 0.1    | 0.0627  | 0.0738   | 0.0987  |
| 4  | 0.05   | 0.06262 | 0.721    | 0.12    |
| 4  | 0.04   | 0.05227 | 0.0825   | 0.283   |
| 4  | 0.02   | 0.04728 | 0.0628   | 0.0936  |
```

I want to create a plot for each id. The plot should show the count of ids in 4 scores. I want to create multiple plots for each id (here separate plots for id 1, 2 and 4).

Here is what I tried till now.

Using sql I created separate column for score classifying each score and used below python code for plotting. Here I was only able to generate single plot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.countplot(x='score', data=df1)
plt.xlabel('Score')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Distribution per score - id 1')
plt.show()
```

Is there any easier way where we can do all this only in python and plot multiple plots?

Comment: [How do I filter specific rows from a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a loop and a histogram with binning in matplotlib as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ids=[1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,4]
score1=[0.05,0.08,0.05,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.05,0.04,0.02]
score2=[0.0608,0.0333,0.0926,0.0425,0.0992,0.0627,0.06262,0.05227,0.04728]
score3=[0.476464,0.8263,0.8694,0.1948,0.1238,0.0738,0.721,0.0825,0.0628]
score4=[0.53535,0.9463,0.9903,0.3958,0.1937,0.0987,0.12,0.283,0.0936]

scoredf=pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,'score1':score1,'score2':score2,'score3':score3,'score4':score4})

uniqueids=scoredf['id'].unique()

for i in uniqueids:
    tempdf=scoredf[scoredf['id']==i]
    tempdf=tempdf.drop(['id'], axis=1)
    plt.hist(tempdf,bins=3)
    plt.xlabel('Score')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title('Distribution per score - id '+str(i))
    plt.show()
```

[image: First Plot:]

[image: Second Plot:]

[image: Third Plot:]